# Conflicting pins between the PCM library and speaker and the NRF24L01

Tags: arduino-nano, pins, speaker

The PCM library uses pin 11 and the NRF24L01 also uses pin 11. I am using an Arduino nano, and don't know if there is any way to change the pins of either the speaker or the transceiver.
https://github.com/damellis/PCM

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't just change pins. Both systems use hardware that is specific to pin 11.

The best you could achieve would be to use a software SPI implementation on other pins to drive the nRF24L01, but that would mean changes to the library you are using to remove the SPI library usage and replace it with your own software SPI implementation.

Comment: So does that mean it's basically impossible?

Comment: Not impossible, just a lot of work, and the results won't be as fast as with hardware SPI.

Comment: Oh :(. Is there no way to edit the PCM library to use another pin? What makes pin 11 so special?

Comment: It's hard-wired to a specific timer to generate the PWM signal. You *could* re-write the PCM library to use different timers and their associated pins, but that would be *more* work and much harder to understand.

Comment: I might be wrong, but didn't pin 11 in the PCM library have also been pin 3? So could it be changed to that?

Comment: I don't know enough about AVR PWM. It may be possible if you can work out the register settings, for which you'll have to refer to the datasheet for the AVR chip. Personally I wouldn't even begin to consider doing audio on a little 8-bit Arduino. Choose a 32-bit MCU with I2S if you must do anything more than a beep.

Comment: I'm just playing a short 2-second audio file.

Comment: @Epicmania, you could try to replace OCR1A with OCR1B in PCM.cpp (and OCIE1A with OCIE1B) to use pin 3. do not change other 1A/1B

Comment: thank you, I have been trying to change it but I changed much more than that(TCCR2A to TCCR2B), I'll try it with just those changes.

Comment: It didn't work :(